# How to convert query results into excel file and store the file as a varbinary in table without accessing any local path in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to convert query results into excel file and store that file as a varbinary in a table. It can be done by accessing local path like below.

```
DECLARE @cmd VARCHAR(8000), @export_directory VARCHAR(300) = 'D:\', @filename VARCHAR(300) = ''

CREATE TABLE ##temp_data(value VARCHAR(100))
INSERT ##temp_data
SELECT 'TEST'

SELECT @filename = 'excelfile.csv'
SELECT @cmd = 'bcp "SELECT * FROM ##temp_data " queryout "#OUTDIR#\#OUTFILE#" -q -S "#SERVER#" -c -t "," -T'

SET @cmd = REPLACE(@cmd, '#DB#', DB_NAME());
SET @cmd = REPLACE(@cmd, '#OUTDIR#', @export_directory);
SET @cmd = REPLACE(@cmd, '#OUTFILE#', @filename);
SET @cmd = REPLACE(@cmd, '#SERVER#', @@SERVERNAME);

EXECUTE master..xp_cmdshell @cmd,no_output
GO

-----------------------------
CREATE TABLE ##VarbinaryExample (id int, DocData VARBINARY(MAX))

INSERT INTO ##VarbinaryExample
SELECT 1, bulkcolumn
FROM OPENROWSET( BULK 'D:\excelfile.csv', SINGLE_BLOB ) AS y 
-----------------------------
GO



SELECT*FROM ##VarbinaryExample
GO
```

But, is it possible without exporting the file into local path ?

Comment: The only way I can think of off the top of my head would be a SQL CLR and combined with memorystream/streamwriter etc.  You can write the csv contents easily to a binary field.  By the way csv isn't an excel file it is a comma separated value file and are very different.  the csv is actually much easier to deal with

Comment: Converting query output to CSV in memory isn't that hard (though it's slow).  You'd wind up with a large `varchar` field.  I'm not sure if you can then convert that to `varbinary`; I never tried.